# need help with z-index property

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a sprite image that is the background of a div and the div contains "li" elements with anchor links in them..I want that when user hovers over links ..diff parts of sprites' image are displayed in div's background..

now sprite was working great until I added a master page to my aspx page..the image hid behind the "Links"..but when I removed the Z-Index property in my css..the image appeared but the links got behind the image :/ so cant hover over links and test if the sprite is working or not..

now how do I set this z-index property so it works fine? new to all this so need help..thnx

Please find my code [here](http://paste.org/pastebin/view/24218)

Comment: What's the rendered ID of that control now? Your `.Replace()` method wouldn't work correctly if it moved into a master page, since its container would have changed.

Comment: I have overridden Render() method so its original ID only now..CSS is giving me problem here..ID is "id0" only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For z-index to work, the element must have

```
position:relative;
```

,

```
position:absolute;
```

or

```
position:fixed;
```

position:relative; is probably what you will need in this case

Comment: its position:relative; only..still wont work